# Database connection via PowerShell failure

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I wrote this function in PowerShell to make connection to the database, but I am getting an error message when I connect server than contain '\' in the server name. Can anyone help?

Error message:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not 
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating 
>   Server/Instance Specified)"

Note: this only happens when I am connecting to server that contains "\" in the servername. The function above works perfectly when I connect to the servername that does not contain special characters.

```
function ExecuteSqlQuery ($Server, $Database, $SQLDBUser, $SQLDBPwd, $SQLQuery) 
{ 
     $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable       
     $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
     $connectionStr = 
  "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;" 
 if($SQLDBUser -ne $null -and $SQLDBPwd -ne $null){
    $connectionStr = "server='$Server';database='$Database';User ID='$SQLDBUser';Password='$SQLDBPwd'"
 }
      $Connection.ConnectionString = $connectionStr 

 $Connection.Open() 
 $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand 
 $Command.Connection = $Connection 
 $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery 
 try 
 {
     $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()     
     $Datatable.Load($Reader)
 } 
 catch {
  return($error)
}
 $Connection.Close()       
 return $Datatable 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about escaping the the slash `\` by using `replace` function?

```
$Server.replace('\\', '\\\\')
$connectionStr = "server='$Server';database='$Database';User ID='$SQLDBUser';Password='$SQLDBPwd'"
```

Comment: Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Comment: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."